# MySQL not responding after I execute SELECT statement

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

I have a Python code where I am having database statements to establish a database connection and insertion statement. Below is the code which I have written. The program is running correctly but when I open MySQL and run `SELECT` statement, there is no response from database. It's stuck for a long time.

```
import MySQLdb

dsn_database = "project"   
dsn_hostname = "localhost"      
dsn_port = 3306                 
dsn_uid = "root"             
dsn_pwd = "pwd" 

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=dsn_hostname, port=dsn_port, user=dsn_uid,             passwd=dsn_pwd, db=dsn_database)

conn.query("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cars""")

conn.query("""CREATE TABLE cars(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20), Price INT)""")

conn.query("""INSERT INTO cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)""")
```

Comment: Since there is no specified problem with this code, this question should go to the Database Administrators site.

Comment: Okay. what could be possible reasons for MySQL not responding for queries?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I slightly improved the formatting and grammar of the post, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Good luck!